# Intel drivers for ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: intel-graphics

I tried install intel graphics driver using these commands.

What is the difference between them ? are these commands really required to install intel drivers ?

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general comment, it is advised to stay away from installing drivers unless there is a problem with the default configuration.

`xserver-xorg-video-intel` is a set of older drivers for Intel. For newer hardware, chances are good that you can uninstall that package. Then, the kernel build-in modesetting drivers are used instead.

`mesa-utils` is just a set of GL utilities, i.e., to display information or test hardware acceleration.